# How to stop `hrule` from breaking centering of text inside `center` environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, rules, standalone

For some reason, placing `\hrule` above `center` environment makes text in that environment to appear left-aligned. Why?

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm,varwidth=100mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

  \begin{center}
    \tiny
    This is text inside center environment (sentence 1).
    This is text inside center environment (sentence 2).
  \end{center}
  %\hrule % uncomment to break centering
  \begin{center}
    \LARGE
    This is text\\ inside center environment\\ (sentence 1).\\
    This is text\\ inside center environment\\ (sentence 2).
  \end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you uncomment `\hrule` line in my code, you'll get the following output:

[image]

Comment: I have no idea why (don't know the details of the `standalone` class), but it seems to be linked to the class in some way. If you  put the `\hrule` in a `\makebox{100mm]`, you have no problem.

Comment: Maybe not the perfect solution you are looking for but using other `documentclass` options such as `article`, `report`, `book`, etc. will produce the desired output. Furthermore, if you keep the same layout and use `\hrulefill` instead of `\hrule`, then it will work as expected. It could be a bug in the `standalone` class? I am not too sure.

Comment: Instead of the `varwidth` option,  enclose all in a `minipage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`standalone` is a very specialist class that has to redefine the entire latex processing flow, by default it does not allow vertical mode material at all, the `varwidth` option allows a limited use of vertical material via an implicit `varwidth` environment from the package of the same name.

`varwidth` needs to be able to disassemble and measure the constructed vertical list and it is the usual issue that while boxes and glue can be removed with `\lastbox` `\unskip` etc, many node types can not be removed and so break the process. `varwidth` takes precautions against some specials and pdftex whatsits, but `\hrule` (a tex primitive not a latex command) isn't handled and so breaks the loop.

See `varwidth.sty` around line 50

```
% Many things may appear on vertical lists that can't be re-processed,
% so they have to be modified.
```

rules are *not* handled by the package.

Comment: @bp2017 luatex...